# How to convert a url from Uppercase to lowercase in nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, configmap

I have written an nginx config map file for my kubernetes deployment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: api-svc
  namespace: api
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    worker_processes 1;
    events { worker_connections 1024; }
    http {
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name my.abc.com;

            location ~* ^/wservce/api {
                proxy_pass http://my.abc.com:80;
            }
        }

    }
```

Now when I hit my.abc.com/wservce/api  it is working fine and sending the request to

**http://my.abc.com:80/wservce/api**
 and I'm getting the response.

But when I hit my.abc.com/WseRvce/API it matches /wservce/api block because I have used ~*
but the request goes to 
**http://my.abc.com:80/WseRvce/API**
 for which we have not written any rules.

I want to send the request to **http://my.abc.com:80/wservce/api** only even if the request comes in uppercase or lowercase.

Solutions I have tried.

1. I tried to hard code the proxy pass but it didn't work. Nginx pod went to crash loop backoff saying .

```
location ~* ^/wservce/api {
                proxy_pass http://my.abc.com:80/wservce/api;
            }
```

2. Tried this map but again it is sending request to uppercase url.

```
    http {
        map $request_uri $lowercase_uri {
            ~^(?i)(.*)$  $1;
        }
        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name my.abc.com;
            location ~* ^/wservce/api {
                rewrite ^ $lowercase_uri break;
                proxy_pass http://my.abc.com:80;
            }
        }
```

In my logs path is - Wservce/API only and gave 404.

3. Tried this also but it is sending the request to uppercase only.

```
location ~* ^/wservce/api {
                rewrite ~* ^/wservce/api/(.*)$ /wservce/api/$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://my.abc.com:80;
            }
```

In my logs path is - Wservce/API only and gave 404.

4. I don't want to use any library for this like lua.

**Note** : Request is directly coming to nginx there is no ingress above it.

**Summary** : whenever I hit a url with Uppercase letters it goes to its corresponding block but in proxy_pass it takes the url with Uppercase while I want it in lowercase.